# jQuery and checkboxes - get previous eleement

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have a rather simple task but I cannot solve it. I cannot understand how jQuery works with checkboxes.

I  have several checkboxes on my page.

```
<input type="hidden" value="121"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="27" name="option_value[12][]" id="option_value_27" class="filtered option_value" cat="121">
```

I am  trying to select the checked ones with that query:

```
var chboxes=$(".option_value:checked");
```

(they all have `.option_value` style)

I am expecting that I will get an array of objects but I get an array of HTML pieces without methods and properties.

Can I get the array of objects?

I need to use `prev()` method.

On this forum I have found solution with `get(0)` but in my case it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to show your markup otherwise we can't tell what `.prev()` has got to do with the question.

Comment: I just need to get previous element. The problem is that I getting simple piece of HTML withouut methoods and propperties.

Comment: I don't think you quite understand how jQuery works, perhaps you should read some beginner docs and get a better feel for it. Also, your question really gives us who want to answer nothing to work with.

Comment: <input type="hidden" value="121"/>                                                                                        <input type="checkbox" value="27" name="option_value[12][]" id="option_value_27"  class="filtered option_value" cat="121">

Answer (score 0):

With so little to go on I can only guess, but maybe something like:

```
$("input").is(":checked").each(function(i) {
    $(this).prev() // this would be the element just before a checked checkbox
});
```

Not quite sure I understand your comment, but:

```
$("input").is(":checked").each(function(i) {
    $("#someButtonID").append($(this).prev());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="option_value" value="one" /> Checkbox 1
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="option_value" value="two" /> Checkbox 2
<input type="checkbox" class="option_value" value="three" /> Checkbox 3

$('.option_value:checked').each(function () { // Loop through all checked checkboxes
    var prev = $(this).prev(); // Do something with previous jQuery object
});
```

​
Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/viktorb/GugSM/1/